# Is there a doc like perlguts/illguts for ruby?

Tags: ruby, perlguts

I recently enjoied the [illustrated perlguts](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.49/index.html) as fun and easy way to see how things are implemented without the need to dig through sources and would love to read such documentation for ruby.

Perlguts provides some information on the workings of the Perl interpreter and describes how to use the Perl API. Illguts i an illustrated version of perlguts.

Are there similar docs for ruby?

Comment: You may want to describe what perlguts is in your question.

Comment: Well, i thought the link would be ok. Will update though.

Comment: Don't forget there's more than one implementation of Ruby. There's MRI, YARV, JRuby, Rubinius, and others as well.

Comment: Right, thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some stuff along those lines:
[The Ruby Hacking Guide](http://rhg.rubyforge.org/) (old, but contains some of that nuts & bolts info)
http://dev-logger.blogspot.com/2008/06/ruby-internals-by-patrick-farley.html

Comment: Thank you. The Hacking Guide is closest to what i was looking for so far.